# RxJava - Observable chain with concatWith and map

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I'm having troubles properly implementing the following scenario using RxJava (v1.2.1):

I need to handle a request for some data object. I have a meta-data copy of this object which I can return immediately, while making an API call to a remote server to retrieve the whole object data. When I receive the data from the API call I need to process the data before emitting it.

My solution currently looks like this:

```
return Observable.just(localDataCall())
                 .concatWith(externalAPICall().map(new DataProcessFunction()));
```

The first `Observable`, `localDataCall()`, should emit the local data, which is then concatenated with the remote API call, `externalAPICall()`, mapped to the `DataProcessFunction`.

This solution works but it has a behavior that is not clear to me. When the local data call returns its value, this value goes through the `DataProcessFunction` even though it's not connected to the first call.

Any idea why this is happening? Is there a better implementation for my use case?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the issue lies in some part of your code that has not been provided. The data returned from `localDataCall()` is independent of the `new DataProcessFunction()` object, unless somewhere within `localDataCall` you use another `DataProcessFunction`.

To prove this to you I will create a small example using `io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.1`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Observable.just(foo())
            .concatWith(bar().map(new IntMapper()))
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
}

static int foo() {
    System.out.println("foo");
    return 0;
}

static Observable<Integer> bar() {
    System.out.println("bar");
    return Observable.just(1, 2);
}

static class IntMapper implements Func1<Integer, Integer>
{
    @Override
    public Integer call(Integer integer)
    {
        System.out.println("IntMapper " + integer);
        return integer + 5;
    }
}
```

This prints to the console:

```
foo
bar
0
IntMapper 1
6
IntMapper 2
7
```

As can be seen, the value `0` created in `foo` never gets processed by `IntMapper`; `IntMapper#call` is only called twice for the values created in `bar`. The same can be said for the value created by `localDataCall`. It will not be mapped by the `DataProcessFunction` object passed to your `map` call. Just like `bar` and `IntMapper`, only values returned from `externalAPICall` will be processed by `DataProcessFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

`.concatWith()` concatenates all items emitted by one observable with all items emitted by the other observable, so no wonder that `.map()` is being called twice.

But I do not understand why do you need `localDataCall()` at all in this scenario. Perhaps you might want to use `.switchIfEmpty()` or `.switchOnNext()` instead.

Comment: But the .map() is part of the second observable chain, it's not connected directly to the first localDataCall() call. The documentation says: "Returns an Observable that emits the items emitted from the current Observable, then the next, one after the other, without interleaving them". The second observable is the externalAPICall() mapped with the map() call. How does the output of the first observable even gets to the map function?

Comment: localDataCall() gives me the local data immediately, so that I can display something to the user while i retrieve the remote data. I always have the local data to return, and always will need to fetch the remote one, so switchIfEmpty/Next is not a good option...

Comment: It's a comment - not an answer.